# HttpPost to MVC partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Allow me to preface this by saying that I did look into other SO questions dealing with this matter, but they were either ASP solutions or not quite exactly what I needed.

My question is as follows, can I make an Http Post request to a method in my controller that returns a partial view if I am using `Html.BeginForm`? I know, and have used, POST methods using BeginForm multiple times, however, those were to ActionResult methods which were responsible for transferring the data stored over into the server. What I would like to do is something as follows:

Say I have this cshtml:

```
<div class="test">
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyPartialViewMethod"), FormMethod.POST) {
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartTimeLabel, Model.StartTime);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime);

   <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
}

</div>
```

Such that in my Controller I could say have the following example method.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult MyPartialViewMethod(Model DynamicDataModel) {
     //Pass the data in the DynamicDataModel into a  new cshtml page and
     //have the partial view it returns be rendered on screen
}
```

So in a nutshell:

1. Make POST request to server passing into it my data values
2. Have server process the data and return the partial view accordingly populated with all the required data.

I imagine that I could take the approach I used to do back in college with php which is AJAX call via JS to php, php spits out html, JS adds the html where it is needed. However, this seems to be a bit too rough.

Comment: If you want to update the existing DOM with the partial view returned by `MyPartialViewMethod` then you need to use ajax (not sure why you think _this seems to be a bit too rough_?)

Comment: Usually, using a form post means you are going to hit the action and then be redirected afterwards.  However, it is possible to hijack the submit method and use your own ajax post instead of the form submit.  Then you can do whatever you want like any other ajax post.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do not think it is rough, however, I have never done it like that; my partial views were always getters, and any dynamic fields I needed were just made on the spot using JavaScript. This would involve it returning I suppose a whole load of html.

Comment: All you need is `$('form').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var data = $(this).serialize(); $(someElement).load('@Url.Action("MyPartialViewMethod"), data); });`

Comment: I see, and so I suppose then that MyPartialViewMethod is still going to return a partialView or, since it is AJAX, will it be an ActionResult instead? @StephenMuecke , I agree though, that doesn't seem too rough.

Comment: `PartialViewResult` is `ActionResult` :)

Comment: Gotcha, many thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can.
you can also do it in ajax with a custom submit buton who call your ajax an jquery,
with something like that and serialize your model.

or just take the controller part if no ajax and submit

```
 $.ajax({       
            url: '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")',
            data: $('#MyPartialViewMethod').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",               
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
              $('html').html(data);          
            },
            error: function (request, error) {

            }
        });

    [HttpPost]
    public actionName(Model myModel)
    {
     do thing with your model
     return PartialView(myModel);
    }
```

an loop